# Any open public data sets for the Rugby World Cup (in England 2015)?

Tags: data-request, sports, sql, txt

The Ruby World Cup 2015 kicked off in England on Sep/18 and runs until Oct/31.
 Wondering what's the state of open data for Rugby. Any open data sets available (incl. teams, players, squads, stadiums, old tournaments, match stats, and so on)?

Ideally the data set is in **an open plain text format** such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc. and **in the public domain (no rights reserved, no copyright)** or using a permissive license (only attribution required, for example).

Any insight appreciated.

Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the sport.db project (incl. rugby.db) - e.g.:

- [opensport/rugby.db](https://github.com/opensport/rugby.db) - free open public domain datasets incl. in plain text [Rugby World Cup 2015](https://github.com/opensport/rugby.db/blob/master/2015/cup.txt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rugby Union data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/rugby-union-data)

Comment: Thanks for the great link. It's not a duplicate. The focus of the question is 1) on open data (for download) that you can (re)use without any restrictions not just any Rugby data (e.g. some Rugby web sites/pages) and 2) on the Rugby World Cup 2015 in England. Cheers.