# How to scrape rugby union data from espn.co.uk

Tags: programming

This is the site I want to gather data from but I'm really not sure where to start.

http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/playerstats?gameId=271423&league=271937

Comment: what data are you looking for, team or player data?

Comment: Player data, they often list all players in a table containing various stats i.e. tackles/meters run etc, from the team that played, that's the table I want.

Comment: Are you looking for just the displayed data or a lot more? Are you trying to follow the advice from http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/rugby-union-data

Comment: I'm trying to scrape the data from the espn site using a script rather than manually copy and pasting the tables presented in the URL I linked. I've done something similar before with curl to download the html source and then with some clever regexp I can get the table. However this site uses something else to display the table, so I was asking if anyone knows how I would be able to just get a text based form of the table.

Answer (score 5):

You can use python, R or other code language as you prefer:

Example for python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325216/parse-html-table-to-python-list

Example for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package

Here just two short examples from stackoverflow. If you want to iterate the process for various tables you can use a for cycle.

Comment: If I download the page using urllib2.urlopen for instance, it doesn't contain the tables. I think that there is some interaction required on the page i.e. selecting the correct tab for the table. How do I emulate that interaction?

Comment: You should check out python's [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) and [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). They're much more advanced than scraping HTML manually.

Answer (score 2):

In python there are many libraries available for web scraping these are some of the important ones [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) etc. In php we have **simple_html_dom.php** which can parse data from websites. You need a good programming skills to scrape websites by these programmes.

The best way for non-programmers would be using some online web scraper such as  [import.io](https://www.import.io/) but let me warn you not many sites work perfectly with this tool.